# Magento 2 : Override class "Magento\Cms\Block\Widget\Block"

Tags: magento2

is their any way to override "Magento\Cms\Block\Widget\Block" class ?
in module ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: which specific method you want to override ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all create `di.xml` file into following location.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Cms\Block\Widget\Block" type="Vendor\Extension\Block\Widget\Block" />
</config>
```

2. Now create `Block.php` Block file in following location

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\Block\Widget\Block.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Block\Widget;

class Block extends \Magento\Cms\Block\Widget\Block
{
        
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for your answer.